# When would you want a UINavigationBar to have multiple UINavigationItems?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm curious, in my experience you set the `UINavigationItem` and then set the title, bar buttons, etc. but `UINavigationBar` allows you to set an array of these items, why would you want to do this? What benefit would multiple bring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common when you have a `UINavigationController` and you push two or more view controllers onto the nav stack. This pushes multiple navigation items on to the nav bar. This is what allows the back button to be titled based on the previous view controller's title.

If you simply add a nav bar to a view then it is unlikely you would have more than one nav item on the nav bar.